# Different HTTP request requiring different authentication header in same thread

Tags: python, jmeter

I have written a test plan using Jmeter to depict a journey of an E2E scenario. It did take me a while to write it as debugging with Jmeter is really not that easy.

Q1) I could write the same journey with python. I have a choice of creating these mini E2Es with either methods and run them.  What do you think, should I use Jmeter or Python? What are pros and cons.  Note these mini E2Es will eventually also be used in performance testing.

Q2) One thing I did notice is that in Jmeter I have to have 2 threads because Each thread uses it's own header manager (mainly because different threads use different APIs from different group which use different method of authentication).

I would like to use this same test plan for performance test as well. Since I have multiple threads (by the way I have marked "Run Thread group Consecutively") will there be an issue with threads colliding , how can I assure that?  How can I tell different APIs on same thread use different authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Python is a programming language and not a testing framework, so probably JMeter or testing tool written in python is the way to go.

To use different  [Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)  in Sampler/API - just put the manager **under** the sampler

> The Header Manager lets you add or override HTTP request headers.

For set of samplera, you can put each Header Manager and samplers under different controllers so each controller will populate different header under its scope

> JMeter now supports multiple Header Managers. The header entries are merged to form the list for the sampler. If an entry to be merged matches an existing header name, it replaces the previous entry, unless the entry value is empty, in which case any existing entry is removed. This allows one to set up a default set of headers, and apply adjustments to particular samplers.

Comment: great.. I like this.. The Header Manager lets you add or override HTTP request headers.  I will try it thank you

Answer (score 0):

JMeter threads are **totally independent** and don't know anything about each other. So you can parameterise HTTP Header Manager using any suitable way ([functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), whatever) so each user would have its own authentication header. You can verify this using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image: JMeter Header Manager Debugging]

---

If you consider Python scripting easier to implement/debug you can take a look at [Locust](https://locust.io/) framework, you will be able to create/debug load tests in Python and view the load test flow in web interface. See [How to Run Locust with Different Users](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-run-locust-with-different-users) article for more information on implementing your scenario with Locust.